# Subscribe to initially null observable property

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm using rxjs with Angular.

I have a class that has a public property that is an observable.

There is another class that must subscribe to that observable.

However the observable is initially null and is initialized after some small delay.

For the moment I fixed this issue with an ugly setTimeout.

What clean fix can I do?

```
class HasAnObservable {
      observableProp: Observable<any> = null;
      constructor() {
            // This initializes the Observable
            this.initObservableProp();
}

class UsesTheObservable {
     constructor(private readonly hasAnObservable: HasAnObservable) 
     {
         this._useTheObservable()
     }

     private _useTheObservable() {
          // Problem is observableProp is initially null
          this.hasAnObservable.observableProp.subscribe()
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you want to improve? It's just guesswork without any code

Comment: I added some code, I can't paste the real code because it's confidential.

Comment: @Platus does your `initObservableProp` initialize the `observableProp` asynchronously? can you tell us what's going on inside that method, of course you don't need to share the private details but just an overall technical overview would be nice.

Comment: What if you initialized it as `Observable.empty()` instead of `null`?

Comment: Don't initialize the observable to `null`, initialize it to an observable. ex: `public observableProp = this.someService.value$`

Answer (score 1):

Your example doesn't make any sense in terms of proper usage of Observables. You can always initialize an Observable, you just don't want to emit any value:

```
class HasAnObservable {
      private observableSource: ReplaySubject<any>;
      observableProp: Observable<any>;

      constructor() {
          this.observableSource = new ReplaySubject();
          this.observableProp = this.observableSource.asObservable();

          // time-consuming function to emit the first value
          setTimeout(() => {
              this.observableSource.next('foobar');
          }, 1000)
      }
}
```

As you can see, observableProp is immediately initialized in the constructor and you can subscribe to it right away. However, the first value will be output with a delay due to your time-consuming initialization function.